# How to use Boolean datatype in SAS?

Tags: data-structures, sas, boolean

In many mainstream programming languages you can use Boolean data-type (for instance, value can be either `true` or `false`) - to represent binary "true/false".

Is there a Boolean data-type in SAS too?

For example, in this code, the variable `is_fruit` is meant to represent a binary `true` (1) or `false` (0) situation. As I am not aware of any Boolean data-types (or `length` types), I work around this using numeric:

```
data is_fruit;
    length fruit_name $ 40 is_fruit 8.;
    input fruit_name $ is_fruit;
    datalines;
apple 1
orange 1
car 0
tree 0
chicken 0
peach 1
mango 1
human 0
;

run;
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

To me this is not a very elegant data structure as the variable `is_fruit` is really a Boolean data-type (not numeric nor character). So my question is again...

Is there a Boolean data-type (or `length` type) for the `is_fruit` above?

Comment: Either attach a format or use `PROC DATASETS` to add extended attributes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Base SAS has only two datatypes: Numeric, and Character.  Numeric has length 3 bytes to 8 bytes possible, character has any length (1 byte or more).

Boolean expressions in SAS are equivalent to numeric values; a 0 or Missing (Null) value is "False", any other value (negative or positive) is "True".  Assigning the result of a boolean expression in SAS to a value results in `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.

Boolean values can be stored in a 3 length Numeric safely, or can be converted to Character if space is truly a concern.  SAS is optimized for 8 byte numerics, though, and other than storage space it doesn't really help to shorten the numeric (internally during processing it will be stored in 8 bytes of RAM).

Answer (score 8):

As @Joe explained, there are only 2 types of data in SAS, numeric and character.

Whenever encountering a logical expression SAS will produce values 1 for True and 0 for False.

Whenever using a numerical value as a condition, only 0 and . are interpreted as False; every other equates to True.

Examples of logical expressions:

```
* Parentheses are optional but make things clearer;

data logicalTest;
  a = (1 < 2);      * results in a = 1;
  b = (1 > 2);      * results in b = 0;
  c = (-10e20 > .); * results in c = 1;
  d = (. = .);      * results in d = 1;
run;
```

As you can see, missing values are treated as numeric, and will always compare smaller than any number. So you need to be cautious comparing values when missing data are involved.

---

### Using constraints

If this is your need, you could always add constraints to a table so that one or more columns can only accept values 0 or 1. For instance:

```
PROC SQL;
  create table logical 
   (id char (12) format=$12.,
    bool num format=1.);

  alter table logical
    add constraint boolean check(bool in (.,0,1))
      message = "Variable bool can only take values 0, 1, or null.";
QUIT;
```

Now if we try to insert incompatible data (last row in the example below), we'll get an error message.

```
PROC SQL;
  insert into logical values ("ABC", 1);
  insert into logical values ("DEF", 0);
  insert into logical values ("GHI", .);
  insert into logical values ("JKL", null);
  insert into logical values ("JKL", 2);
QUIT;
```

Log shows:

```
27         PROC SQL;
28           insert into logical values ("ABC", 1);
NOTE: 1 row was inserted into WORK.LOGICAL.

(...)

32           insert into logical values ("JKL", 2);
ERROR: Variable bool can only take values 0, 1, or null. Add/Update failed for data set WORK.LOGICAL because data value(s) do not 
       comply with integrity constraint boolean.
NOTE: This insert failed while attempting to add data from VALUES clause 1 to the data set.
NOTE: Deleting the successful inserts before error noted above to restore table to a consistent state.
NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
```

---

### Using formats

You could also go further and add a format to the bool variable:

```
PROC FORMAT;
  VALUE boolean 0 = "False"
                1 = "True"
                . = "Unknown";
QUIT;

PROC SQL;
  create table logical 
   (id char (12) format=$12.,
    bool num format=boolean.);

  alter table logical
    add constraint boolean check(bool in (.,0,1))
      message = "Variable bool can only take values 0, 1, or null.";
QUIT; 

PROC SQL;
  insert into logical values ("ABC", 1);
  insert into logical values ("DEF", 0);
  insert into logical values ("GHI", .);
  insert into logical values ("JKL", null);
QUIT;
```

[image: "Boolean" field with format]